# The size of textbox getting reduced automatically when it is made both draggable(using javascript) and resizable(using jquery))

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a textbox which I am making it resizable using jquery and draggable using javascript. While I click the textbox it should be resizable. The function of dragging and resizing is going on well, but when I am clicking the textbox to resize it, the size of the textbox is getting little bit reduced automatically.

```html
<html>
  <style>
    .drag {
      position:absolute;
      z-index:0;
    }

    #A {
      position:absolute;
      z-index:0;
      width:20px;
      height:10px;
    }
  </style>
  <input type="text" class="drag" id="A">
  <script>        
    $('#A').on('click',function() { 
      $(this).resizable({
        ghost:true
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

If I don't add the resizable code, then on clicking the textbox nothing happens, but on adding the resizable code, the size is getting reduced automatically.
Please suggest me the solution for this.

Comment: @Mosh Feu, Thank u for the edit.. I have searched and found that this bug is there in jquery when using the border-box, but I am not using that, still getting the problem.. Someone please help.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle?